# Add existing JS object to Angular app as a dependency

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular and trying to figure out how to inject some external objects into Angular.

I have a JS script defining a global Payment object with some methods on it. I'd like to somehow import it (the Payment object) into an Angular service (from what I understood the service would be the place to that). How exactly does one go about that?

What I'd like to achieve in the end would be something like:

```
app.controller("myController", [PaymentService, function (payment) {....}]);
```

Comment: Why do you want to add it as a dependency in the first place, if its already a global JS object?

Comment: @Pr0gr4mm3r testing comes to mind...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work :

```
app.factory('PaymentService',['$window', function($window){ 
  return $window.Payment;
}]);
```

Using a factory is an occasion to add additional behavior, for example adding methods or checking that the global object is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it either as a value:

```
 angular.module('foo').value('PaymentService',window.Payment);
```

or as a constant:

```
 angular.constant('foo').value('PaymentService',window.Payment);
```

Comment: You must mean `window.Payment`, not `PaymentService`.

Comment: Indeed, fixed. Thanks.